# Mysql update multiple tables, thread safe

Tags: mysql, transactions, thread-safety

Is this update thread safe if I use innoDB.

```
UPDATE Books, Orders
SET Orders.Quantity=Orders.Quantity+2,
Books.InStock=Books.InStock-2
WHERE Books.BookID=Orders.BookID
 AND Orders.OrderID = 1002;
```